# How to enable scrolling for IOS in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I am building the app, which I test on all 3 devices: IOS, Android, Web. I used SingleChildScrollView and it works fine for Android and Web, however, it doesn't work on IOS. Any tips on what's going on?

Code:

```
final leftPanel = Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, top: 20),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (ctx, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                          appBar.preferredSize.height -
                          mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                      0.05, //Change here to 1 for landscape layout
                  child: leftPT),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: (mediaQuery.size.height -
                        appBar.preferredSize.height -
                        mediaQuery.padding.top) *
                    0.9,
                      child: TaskList(_userTasks, _deleteTask),),
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing about `SingleChildScrollView` or what I'm seeing in your code to prevent scrolling on iOS. You need to create a minimal working app with the problem, and then post an issue with flutter project on github so that the developers assess the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I am one month into coding, and I haven't really used github yet, but I feel like it's a good time to try it out.